# Always receiving FileNotFoundException, even with file in SRC folder

Tags: java, file, exception, file-io

I'm currently trying to write a program that will read in a file line by line and add each line to an arrayList. My other function is supposed to sort the items from that buffer, then write them to a text file. However, I keep getting a FileNotFoundException, even when my file is sitting in the src directory, as well as the directory with my .class file. My code is as follows

```
public static ArrayList<String> readDictionary(String filename, 
ArrayList<String> buffer) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    File f = new File(filename);
    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(f);
    //Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    boolean add = true;

    while (fileIn.hasNextLine() == true) {
        for (String s : buffer) {
            if (fileIn.nextLine().equals(s)) {
                add = false;
            }
        }
        if (add == true) {
            buffer.add(fileIn.nextLine());
        }
        add = true;
    }
    fileIn.close();
    return buffer;
}

public static void writeDictionary(String filename, ArrayList<String> buffer) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    File f = new File(filename);
    Collections.sort(buffer, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    Path file = Paths.get(filename);
    Files.write(file, buffer);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
    ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
    readDictionary("inputtest.txt", buffer);
}

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: inputtest.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:611)
at UltimateDictionary.readDictionary(UltimateDictionary.java:18)
at UltimateDictionary.main(UltimateDictionary.java:46)
```

I tested this program by setting filename equal to "inputtest.txt", and that file is sitting in my src directory with the .java file, but it still throws the error. Also, how can I close the files? f.close() gives me an error.

Comment: Could you provide detailed error message?

Comment: I edited in the error message, as well as the main method I'm using to test it. I don't see how I'm getting this error when the text file is sitting in the directory.

Comment: What about providing an  absolute path? It might come from the fact the application is started from another working directory.

Comment: You aren't executing from your `src` directory. *Ergo* a file put there won't be found by its name alone.

Comment: @EJP do you know where it would be executing from? I wrote an earlier program that had to read in image files, and putting the images in the 'src' directory was what allowed them to be read in.

Comment: @Fabien how can I find the absolute path if I can't read the file initially? Don't I need to use .getAbsolutePath() for that to work?

Comment: Try printing `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()` when your application starts up. Note that it will be different inside and outside an IDE, but your `src` folder won't be there at runtime anyway so you already need to find a better place for the file.

Comment: Have you tried `/inputtest.txt` or `/src/inputtest.txt`, `ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream(path) ? I really cant see to your project folder.

Comment: @StephenBurns you're right, that's because packaging your application, depending on your packaging method, what is in src directory will be in your classpath, maybe in your current directory, but it's not always true. Trying to define a File specifying only the name, without the full path, it has to be in your current directory, the same directory returned by System.getProperty("user.dir"), that possibly is also the project directory running from inside an IDE. I assume that at runtime your method will receive, as an argument, an absolute path or relative to the current directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file in your src or .class directory, could only mean that the file is in classpath, while new File(filename); search the current working directory. To search classpath, change readDictionary method, after File f = new File(filename);  add:

```
    if (!f.exists()) {
        URL url = <yourclassname>.class.getResource(filename);
        if (url != null)
            f =  new File(url.getPath());
    }
```

you have to use yourclassname.class because the method is static. Should work also:

```
if (url == null)
    url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(filename);
```

Comment: The URL won't even *be* a file URL if the application is packaged in a JAR, as is normal.

Comment: @EJP the question is about directory, not jar file. *Your statement is misleadeng at all and doesn't add any knowledge.* If he wanted to read the file from a jar, he should use getResourceAsStream, getting an inputStream, but is not what is wanted, as a regular file is wanted.

Comment: @EJP the application can be packeged in a jar, but this do not mean that the build process includes anyting, then the application could be e web application so what inside src would be *normally* packaged in WEB_INF/classes, who can tell?

Comment: That is exactly my point. As you don't know the answer to that any more than I do, you don't have any reason to *assume* that the URL will be of a file.